# Text file being scanned but not stored in variables

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I am trying to have this file read / scanned in, and have the lines split into separate variables, but am unable to see any output.  Is there anyway to check this?

sample lines from file:

Smith, John, 123-789-4560, Birthday 1/1/2000

Picasso, Pablo, 123-654-0987, House Painter

after its read in do i need to do get and set?

```
public final void readFile() throws IOException
{
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C://ContactList/ContactList.txt"))) 
    {
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            String currentLine = scan.nextLine();
            String[] splitString = currentLine.split(",");
            importNameLast = splitString[0].trim();
            importNameFirst = splitString[1].trim();
            importPhoneNumber = splitString[2].trim();
            importContactNotes = splitString[3].trim();

        }
    }
}

private void populateContactList()
{
    System.out.println("Initializing Contacts");
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    contactList.add(new Contact("Doe", "John", "123-456-7890", "null"));
    contactList.add(new Contact("Doe", "Jane", "123-456-7890", "null"));
    contactList.add(new Contact(importNameLast, importNameFirst, importPhoneNumber, importContactNotes));

}
```

Comment: Hi, please create an [mcve]. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Your question is kind of bad in the sense that the titile is wrong (what are jsf text files?) and your tags are way to broad If the answer below is what you are looking for, the JSF tag is wrong. If it is not, the java tag is wrong. The java-ee tag is wrong anyways and since there is no facelet posted that tag is wrong to.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSF. JSF is in the context of this question merely a model view presenter framework. Having trouble with creating alone the model has nothing to do with JSF. You'd have had exactly the same problem when doing the same in any other web application framework or even a plain Java application class with a `main()` method (which by the way allows much easier testing). Do so first using a plain Java application class and once you got it to work, then simply let the JSF backing bean execute the same code.